Create user service that runs with superuser privileges
I have a script that requires superuser/root privileges to run:
$ cat /usr/local/sbin/disable_audio_powersave.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo '0' > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save

and a systemd service that executes it:
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/disable_audio_powersave.service
[Unit]
Description=Disable audio powersaving
Require=default.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/disable_audio_powersave.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Is there any way to have both these files in my home user directory?
That is, to move the script to e.g. ~/bin and the service to ~/.config/systemd/user/?
Or will the script not execute with the required privileges?
The reason I want them in my home directory and not the system-wide directory is to easily be able to track the files with a git dotfile manager (yadm) that only has access to the home directory.

In principle, doing that would defeat the purpose of having separate superuser privileges, as your regular user account would likely be able to modify or delete and recreate those files to make them do anything. Well, unless you take care to put them in directories the user can't write to. Though, anyway, I suppose all that might not really matter if that's a personal machine where anything important is owned by the regular user anyway. I think you could at least try symlinking the service file from /etc/systemd to ~ if you want to.

@ilkkachu Yes of course, that makes a lot of sense in hindsight.
